# Facebook Server-Side Auth: Why does the access token request require a redirect uri?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-authentication

In the server side auth flow, Facebook does not execute any redirects after the app requests the access token.

So why does the access token request require a redirect_uri parameter?

Answer (score 1):

See section [4.1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-10#section-4.1.1) of the [OAuth 2.0 Spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-10).

`redirect_uri` is a required paramter when obtaining an access token.

From the spec:

> The authorization server MUST:
>
> - Validate the client credentials (if present) and ensure they match
>   the authorization code.
> - Verify that the authorization code and redirection URI are all
>   valid and match its stored association.